# How to manipulate windows file and folder attribute with PHP?

Tags: php, windows, file, attributes, directory

Is this any possible way to set or change windows file and folder attribute with php?

I'm creating desktop.ini file in some folders with php.
But I need to make it HSA - Hidden, System file, Archive -
In addition I need to make folder read-only which is a R flag.

Is there anyway to do that with PHP ? 
please help me!

Comment: Guess you need to use the [`attrib`](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-file-attributes-windows-attribexe) program, you could try run it with shell_exec or similar. If your trying to do it on a users file system and not on the server then its not going to work obviously.

Comment: I'm running php on my local machine and I want to make changes on local file and folders. no server at all.

Comment: That's what I meant, server = local..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the answer,

```
exec("attrib +r <any directory>");
exec("attrib +h +s +a desktop.ini");
```