# how to set and get file attributes on txt files

Tags: php

Is there any way to set and get a file attribute on a `txt` file, using `php`
I tried with xattr - `xattr_set('file.txt', 'abc', 5)` but it only works on specific file systems
I'm on windows in localhost and a standard remote hosting file system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manipulate windows file and folder attribute with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629856/how-to-manipulate-windows-file-and-folder-attribute-with-php)

Comment: @Michel, no, I don't want to change status of a file - `read only` etc. I just need an integer param as an attribute

Comment: Can you define "standard remote hosting file system" ? (and some more info on this 'integer param' holding an attribute)

Comment: I actually doubt that you can set an arbitrary file attribute on a FAT or NTFS file system.

Comment: @arkascha - is there a way to check this, to be sure?

Comment: I would suggest you take a look into the documentation...